# npm private repo with https

Tags: node.js, npm, https, ca

I a have a private npm registry (mirror of the public one) which I use for development. I'm trying to install tileserver-gl, which has several native dependencies. These dependencies are built using node-pre-gyp package. Node-pre-gyp does not support http connections (there's an if-expression that throws an error if http is used), so I had to setup https on my repo. The certificate-chain is created (ca and one intermediate cert) and installed on the development machine (CentOS 7). Curl works correctly on the https-address and shows the certificate is valid. OpenSSl also shows the certificate as valid.

Npm config edit contains:

```
registry=https://repo.internal/npm/
cacert=/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/repo.pem
```

The problem is, when I try to run npm i command, the command fails with one of two errors.

First one is **UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT**.

The second error is **ECONNREFUSED** (npm tries to use port 80 even though https is specified). This happens when I use `npm config set strict-ssl=false`

Any ideas where the problem is?